# Hadoop reducer output order when output key is NullWritable

Tags: hadoop, reducers

I am writing a `hadoop` application whose final output is a `bmp` image. I change the output format to `byte`, here is my question: what will the `reducer output order` be if I set the output key being `NullWritable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output key type of your reducer has no affect on the ordering of your reducer output - that's controlled by the reducer input key, and its natural ordering via the keys `compareTo` method or the raw comparator if configured.

So the order will be the same order by which records are processed by your reducer (unless you reducer is maintaining state between keys / values and flushing this state on a regular basis)